# What is the difference between PostgreSQL 9.0 Replication and Slony-I?

Tags: postgresql, replication

Is there still any use for Slony-I, and if so, what is it? For clarification, from 9.0 Postgresql supports built in streaming replication.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This article covers it well: http://scanningpages.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/9-0-streaming-replication-vs-slony/